# Freeze <div> at top of screen, make the remaining <div> fill screen and scroll

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have an Angular 7 (Angular 2, colloquially) application that I need to style correctly.

There are two `<div>` tags. One `<div>` tag should render in whatever vertical space is needed. There should never be a scroll bar.

The second `<div>` needs to fill the remaining screen, allowing the user to scroll through what could not be rendered on the page.

The desired outcome is much like Gmail, where the tools are locked in place at the top of the browser and the inbox is scroll-able.

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f7dxzo) of my toy example. The scrolling behavior is correct, but I can't get the second `div` to fill the remaining screen.

Here is the component's HTML template:

```
<div>
  <mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <mat-toolbar-row>
      <span>Really Important Stuff</span>
    </mat-toolbar-row>
  </mat-toolbar>

  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>

<div class="scroll-container">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS I'm applying to the template:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
}

.mat-form-field {
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 100%;
}

/* I want the scroll container to fill the remaining screen height */
.scroll-container {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

I do not want to add any more JS dependencies to my project if it's avoidable. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using flexbox it can be done by adding this css

```
body{
  overflow: hidden;
}

table-filtering-example{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 95vh;
}

.scroll-container {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

you can refer to this forked stackblitz with changes 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f7dxzo-mqimyr?file=app%2Ftable-filtering-example.css

Comment: This is so simple. Thank you! It's going to require me to really think about how I'm structuring my components and where I place the ng selectors, which will only improve my project and my knowledge.